# some POSIX Bracket Expressions not working

Tags: vim, regular-expression

For example when I'm trying to find and replace something using

```
g/[:digit:]/s/1/2/g
```

Vim showing error: `Pattern not found: [:digit:]`, while the string contains digits.

Following POSIX Bracket Expressions are not working: [:digit:], [:xdigit:], [:upper:], [:lower:], [:print:], [:cntrl:]

At the same time all the others POSIX Bracket Expressions (like [:alnum:], [:alpha:], [:blank:] etc. work pretty well.

Vim version 7.4

Comment: `g/[[:digit:]]/s/1/2/g` (or `\d`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[:foo:]` bracket expression is meant to be **used inside a [...] collection**, like this:

```
:g/[[:digit:]]/s/1/2/g
```

This allows you to specify multiple (alternative; otherwise it would be concatenation) groups, and mix with other characters, e.g.: `[[:space:][:digit:]abc]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! But why some bracket expressions require that so called [:foo:] bracket expression, while others don't?

Comment: I think you just got false positives from those.